# Spring AOP IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy12

Tags: spring, proxy, spring-aop

I am trying to configure one advice in an existing spring project.
Following configuration works fine for a single package but when pointcut expression try to apply that advice on all packages its giving following error.

My Configuration:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="loggingPointcut" expression="execution(* com.abc.businessprocess.operation..*.execute(..))" />
    <aop:advisor id="methodLoggingAdvisor" advice-ref="methodLoggingAdvice" pointcut-ref="loggingPointcut" />
</aop:config>
```

I tried with annotation also but it was giving same error.
I tried with CGLIB also even after using that its giving same error.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [$Proxy12 implementing com.fmr.ast.common.businessprocess.util.Timeable,com.fmr.ast.common.businessprocess.operation.Operation,com.fmr.commons.taskmanager.core.Task,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.fmr.ips.businessprocess.operation.goalsetup.GetLeveledIRGExpInc] for property 'getRawDetailedLeveledExpInc'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy12 implementing com.fmr.ast.common.businessprocess.util.Timeable,com.fmr.ast.common.businessprocess.operation.Operation,com.fmr.commons.taskmanager.core.Task,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.fmr.ips.businessprocess.operation.goalsetup.GetLeveledIRGExpInc] for property 'getRawDetailedLeveledExpInc': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy12 implementing com.fmr.ast.common.businessprocess.util.Timeable,com.fmr.ast.common.businessprocess.operation.Operation,com.fmr.commons.taskmanager.core.Task,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [com.fmr.ips.businessprocess.operation.goalsetup.GetLeveledIRGExpInc] for property 'getRawDetailedLeveledExpInc': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:386)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the exception trace this is what I suspect:

`GetLeveledIRGExpInc` is a concrete class that implements three interfaces: `Timeable`, `Operation`, `Task`. You have a bean of this type declared in your context, which gets proxied because of your AOP config. This means that the runtime type of the bean won't be `GetLeveledIRGExpInc` any more, it will be `$Proxy12` (JDK proxy) which still implements the above three interfaces, but is not a subtype of the concrete class `GetLeveledIRGExpInc`.

There is another bean somewhere in your context that needs a bean of this type to be injected into a property named `getRawDetailedLeveledExpInc`. When Spring tries to inject the proxied bean into that property, it fails, because the property's type is incompatible with the bean's runtime type.

The fundamental problem is that you try to apply a very generic logging aspect using JDK proxying mechanism which can only advise methods declared on interfaces. Try using `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">` so that classes without implemented interfaces can be advised as well. This would resolve the above detailed problem, as the generated CGLIB proxy for `GetLeveledIRGExpInc` will actually be a subtype of it. (Don't forget to add cglib to your dependencies for this to work.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Zagyi for wonderful explanation, As I mentioned in my post I have tried this with CGLIB using <aop:config proxy-target-class="true"> and tried false value also for this but was getting same error. Any other possible reason?

Comment: You couldn't get the same error if the CGLIB enhancer were used for proxying. A proxy created by CGLIB looks something like this: `GetLeveledIRGExpInc$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$<some hex number>`. Your stacktrace clearly shows that JDK proxies (`$Proxy12`) are in place, so there must be some problem with your AOP configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zagyi, As you told I tried it again with CGLIB and its working now. I have added default constructor into all operations and that fixed my problem.